# How to stack arrays of different shapes? Make a 3d-array from multiple 2d-arrays of different lengths

Tags: python, arrays, list

**Some context**

Code used for reading data from multiple files and stacking it to form a list of 2d arrays that imitates numpy stacking:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def read_file(files):
    data = []
    for i in range( len(files) ):
                try:   
                    ehists.append( pd.read_csv(files[i], delimiter = "\t", compression='gzip', header=None).to_numpy() )
                except pd.errors.EmptyDataError:
                    pass
    return data


foldername = "datafolder"

### reading files with names file1, file2.......
files = glob.glob("./"+foldername+"/file*")

3dData = read_file(files)
```

**Main query**

For simplicity, let's say that each file has 3 columns, but have different lengths (number of rows). Column 1 represents time, columns 2 and 3 are some data points at that time. So, a typical file looks somewhat like:

```
10    0.34    1.37
15    0.39    1.42
20    0.45    1.47
25    0.57    1.53
30    0.68    1.62
35    0.82    1.89
40    0.92    1.97
```

In order to plot a distribution histogram of column 2 values from all files at different times, I parse over the list of arrays using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t_end = 1000
t = np.arange(0, t_end, 1)

y = []

for time in t:
    y_t = []
    for i in range( len(3dData) ):           ## iterating over files(2d-arrays)
        for j in range( np.shape(3dData[i])[0] ):  ## iterating over rows in the 2d-array
            if 3dData[i][j,0] == time:
                y_t.append( 3dData[i][j,1] )
    y.append( y_t )

## Hist of values at t=10
t0 = 10
plt.hist(y[t0])
plt.show()
```

What I want to achieve is working out for me. However, since I have ~100000 2d-arrays in the list, the above code takes quite long to run. I feel that the inconsistency of the object types is resulting in slower processing while parsing through the data. (Am I correct in thinking so, and) Is there a way to stack 2d arrays of different shapes without having to pad the 2d array data?

P.S.: I can provide more info if needed and I will be more than happy to receive advice/suggestions on how to make this code more efficient.

*Thank you for your time and energy!*

Comment: Please read [ask] and how to provide a [mre]. Your question needs to be a bit more focused and best if it will address a specific code problem and be less general

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thanks for your input, I edited the question to include more details.

Answer (score 1):

There are likely better ways to do this. `numpy` will probably be more performant for manipulating arrays.

But here's one way to normalize the lengths of a list of lists using `zip_longest()`. This will incur an iteration through the entire data set as list items are pulled through two levels of zip iterators.

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>>
>>> rows = [[random.randint(100, 999) 
...          for _ in range(random.randint(5, 10))] 
...         for _ in range(10)]
...
>>> for row in rows:
...     print(row)
...     
[826, 735, 223, 394, 885, 122, 259, 899, 788, 121]
[984, 405, 185, 984, 727, 901, 704, 526, 936]
[617, 814, 801, 382, 138, 245, 225]
[314, 478, 103, 509, 559, 687, 124, 869, 596]
[982, 741, 714, 489, 613, 392, 940, 577, 155]
[752, 262, 365, 213, 451, 925, 610]
[555, 288, 277, 975, 573]
[507, 753, 537, 721, 629]
[235, 971, 970, 721, 571]
[367, 627, 335, 955, 410, 393, 387, 935, 793]
>>> 
>>> padded_rows = [list(row) for row in zip(*zip_longest(*rows, fillvalue='#'))]
>>> for row in padded_rows:
...     print(row)
...     
[826, 735, 223, 394, 885, 122, 259, 899, 788, 121]
[984, 405, 185, 984, 727, 901, 704, 526, 936, '#']
[617, 814, 801, 382, 138, 245, 225, '#', '#', '#']
[314, 478, 103, 509, 559, 687, 124, 869, 596, '#']
[982, 741, 714, 489, 613, 392, 940, 577, 155, '#']
[752, 262, 365, 213, 451, 925, 610, '#', '#', '#']
[555, 288, 277, 975, 573, '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']
[507, 753, 537, 721, 629, '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']
[235, 971, 970, 721, 571, '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']
[367, 627, 335, 955, 410, 393, 387, 935, 793, '#']
>>>
```

Not sure what's meant by tampering with the data. This approach simply copies references to the data from list to list - so it's not performing any operations on the data itself.